# Symfony2 best way to organise javascript in twig template

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

It's not about libraries, it's about custom scripts.

I know two solutions:

1. To write everything in one big file (many functions or custom library)
2. To write pieces of scripts in twig templates

Both solutions do not really like. In the first case, we must to copy assets after every update. In the second case, it is not very easy to make changes and difficult to reuse code.

Maybe you know any other solutions?

Comment: For me it is better to have separate javascript from html(twig) . What you can do is have multiple .js files to organize better (multiple .js for bundle, for example)

Comment: Multiple .js files is multiple requests to server. Do you use a compressor for this (YUI Compressor)?

Comment: you can minify/obfuscate the javascript file. You are right, more files is more request to the server, but only at the beginning, later you have the js in the cache.

Comment: How I can use variables ( like a path, id, etc. ) in this case?

Comment: in the javascript file? jquery, and for path(routing) use the FOSJsRoutingBundle ([here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I organize my javascripts in separate files and I try to form namespaces and classes, the problem with instantiation and and values from twig I solve using sort of constructors for my Classes as in example bellow:

```
{%block javascripts}
  {{ parent() }}
  <script type='text/javascript' src={{ asset('path/to/my/SpecificClass.js')}} 

   SpecificClass.attribute1 = {{ value_from_twig }}
   SpecificClass.attribute2 = {{ other_value_from_twig }}

{%endblock}
```

I find this way cleaner but if you'd like to separate completely the js code from the twig then I think you should consider an API architecture, using `AngularJs`, `BackboneJs`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in your question that you have to copy the assets after every change if you have just one big file. That's not necessarily true, you could use assetic to load dynamically that file in the prod environment like this:

```
{% javascripts
        '@dsarhoyaDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/demo.js'
        output='compiled/main.js'
    %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

For the prod enviroment just run: assetic:dump --env=prod

Don't know if that tips the balance either way. In my experience, is best to use a combination of both: big common files and pieces of specific scripts.